# How are national average calculated in consumer website?

Tags: collegescorecard

How does the Scorecard compute national averages on the consumer website?  Example: the Scorecard reports national average "salary after attending" as $33,410, but when computed using the data download, I get $32,850. Is the difference due to suppression in the download data or something else?

Comment: What is *the Scorecard*? What *consumer website*? National averages *of what*? Please [edit] in some links or explanations. This is an international forum.